# Retrieve value from the database, as empty json {} or Null, male separate cases

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I retrieve an column/record value from a table for an associated model.

The value can be Null or an empty json {}

I have the following code(cat.path is a JSONField):

```
cat = Cat.objects.order_by('?')[0]

if cat.path is None:
```

It is catching both situations, but I want to have separate cases.

Comment: is the `cat.path` a JSONField?

Comment: yes is a JSONField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be considered as a dict.
[According to the Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField): 
*if you give the JSONfield a default, ensure it’s a callable such as dict (for an empty default) or a callable that returns a dict (such as a function).*

To check whether it's `Null` or an empty json `{}` (Empty Dict)

```
if cat.path is None or (isinstance(cat.path,dict) and not cat.path):
    pass
```